# Remote Desktop access from windows VM running on linux host + vmware server 2

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vmware-server

I am trying to access a windows VM through RDP. I am using NAT and a linux host. I am not getting a proper answer on the web. Can anyone help /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, question belongs to serverfault.

Implementing a bridged connection and use that IP for remote access is the easy way. Or if you are using NAT, there is a way to connect to guest OS by a facility that VM provides which is a console connection to the guest OS. Check your VM settings for that and enable that. After that you will be able to connect to guest os by hostos ip : port that you specified while console configuration.

Comment: "there is a way to connect to guest OS by a facility that VM provides which is a console connection to the guest OS. "

thanks but that's the obsure part I wanted to resolve :)
I am using vmware server 2.. if that helps

Comment: I haven't used VMware server. But their site says remote console connection is available from version 2 as a Web browser add-on. I checked their server guide which is available here - http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmserver2.pdf. In that check page no 130.